# JPA2 and EclipseLink - try to understand caching

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I want to understand caching in JPA 2 using EclipseLink as persistence provider. I don't know if my my thinking is correct.

For example:
I use JTA transactions. On some entity class called `A` I have declared `@Cacheable(true)` annotation. I invoke a method from EJB bean which updates `A.class` object. On the first I invoke `em.find(A.class, 1)`. My question is what is the searching order. I present my way of thinking.

1. `EntityManager` searches entity in the L2 cache. If `EM` find the object, it copy the object to the L1 cache and stops searching.
2. Else `EntityManager` searches entity in the L1 cache. If `EM` find the object, it stops searching.
3. Else `EntityManager` searches entity in database. If `EM` find the object, it put the object to the L1 cache and stops searching.

When I find object, I modify a few fields and I want to invoke `em.merge(aClassRepresentant)`. I think that when the transactions stops `EntityManager` puts merged `aClassRepresentant` to the L2 cache and destroys itself. Do I think correctly?

Comment: Good question. So if the L2 cache is invalidated via `emf.getCache().evictAll()` then during the next query, going back to step#1, we will lost the updated version of the object since L1-cache will be searched instead?

Comment: Now I think that step#1 and step#2 should be swapped. L1 cache has lifecycle like a transaction life cycle. When we invoke new buisness method, L1 cache is empty. If we want to find an entity on the previous and L2 cache does not contains that entity, then `EntityManager` gets searched object from data source. If whe find the object in the data source, EclipseLink copy tat object to L1 and L2 cache. Of course we must use `EntityManager.find()` method or `NameqQuery` which gets entity by `id` or indexes defined in `@Index` annotation placed on the entity class.

Comment: `NamedQuery` must return single result, if no, found entities will not be placed in the L2 cache...

Comment: Order would be EM cache, then EMF cache, then database.  If it hits the database and it is in a transaction with changes, what it reads will only be put in the EM cache until the transaction commits, when it will merge what it has into the EMF cache.